# modify column names order when using pivot_wider()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling to find a way of changing column names order when pivoting them to wider. When doing a pivot, column name gets `Val1 AA`, `Val1 AB` order and I'd like to reverse it to have `AB Val1`, `AB Val1` etc. I didn't find a way to do it from pivot_wider package. I cannot use explicit column name values since they are dynamically changed. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
library(tidyverse)
Rank <- c('AA','AB','AC')
Val1 <- c(10,20,30)
Val2 <- c(40,50,60)
data <- data.frame(Rank,Val1, Val2)  
data %>% pivot_wider(values_from = 2:3, names_from = Rank, names_sep = " ")
```

Comment: `data %>% pivot_wider(values_from = 2:3, 
                     names_from = Rank, 
                     names_glue = "{Rank}_{.value}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `names_glue` instead

```
data %>% pivot_wider(values_from = 2:3, names_from = Rank, names_glue = "{Rank} {.value}")

  `AA Val1` `AB Val1` `AC Val1` `AA Val2` `AB Val2` `AC Val2`
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1        10        20        30        40        50        60
```

Comment: That was ultra fast, thank you very much!